# Orbit slider caption and link on same slide

Tags: html, slideshow, href, caption, orbit

I have successfully implemented the orbit slider, everything works, i just can't get the slides to display captions and also have links on the pictures.

Example code:

```
<img src="images/slideshow/dummy-images/1.jpg"  data-caption="#htmlCaption" />
```

this works perfectly

```
<a href="url here"><img src="images/slideshow/dummy-images/halo.jpg" /></a>
```

also works perfectly, but

```
<a href="url here"><img src="images/slideshow/dummy-images/halo.jpg" data-caption="#htmlCaption" /></a>
```

makes the picture disappear and nothing will show. No error message, no nothing.

every orbit file is untouched and I still can't get it to work.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help appreciated,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sources suggest using the minified version causes problems with anchors. So, first just try not using a min version. Also, it is suggested to replace ul and li with div and a.

This is a bit old but might be helpful, check the last bits: https://github.com/zurb/orbit/issues/7

Comment: I moved the data-caption to the a tag and now it works perfectly! I didn't need to change anything else!

now my code looks like this:

    <a href="url here" data-caption="#htmlCaption" ><img src="images/slideshow/dummy-images/halo.jpg" /></a>

this way it displays the caption and also has the link on the image!

You solved what i couldn't in 2 hours! THANKS!